# Can we pair two smart watches without a phone?

Tags: android, wear-os

As far as I know, wear smartwatches are designed to be companion devices that stay connected to your smartphone. Without a phone around, though, they aren't entirely useless.They'll still function as watches, for one, giving you the time and the date.

But I am not sure if there are any changes to this in any of the latest updates. So I want to know if it is possible to pair two smart watches and send messages using messageapi without the help of a smartphone.Just curious to know ?

Ideally, I want two watches to interact using messageapi to send messages. Is it possible to do without a smartphone?

Comment: THis http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119015/how-does-the-communication-between-smartwatch-and-smartphone-work-over-the-same says that this type of smartwatch communicates with a phone over WiFi, so apparently a smartwatch has WiFi. I suggest you migrate this question to the android enthusiasts forum

Answer (score 0):

Well, if talking about pairing *two watches with each other*, you definitely **CAN NOT** do this.

---

But, if you want to extend the abilities of an android smartwatch, you may add some features based on WiFi connection. Since a watch can be connected to a WiFi network, you're able to send messages and do some other stuff with it.
Also you should check up the [Together feature](https://www.android.com/wear/together/), but as I may say, it's built on the interaction of two handhelds, but not wearables.